# How many app can we upload on Play Store from single account

Tags: android, mobile-application, android-account

I have a simple question that i could not find on internet. I have an individual account of android developer account i wanted to ask that how many apps can i upload to my android developers account. and if i have a company account on android how many apps can i upload on play store from company account.

```
   Maximum number of apps can be upload from individual android developer account?
```

Thanks

Comment: Infinite I believe, There is no reason for them to limit the number of apps. and they said that you have to pay 25$ once, not for limit number of applicaions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit, how insanely many apps are you thinking about producing? ;)

Comment: Not upload apps by my own but to allow public to upload apps who don't have account on google :)